# Django-money: decimal_places doesn't work

Tags: django

I'm using `django-money` for representing price info in my project.

I don't want to show any decimal point so I set `decimal_places` as zero, but it always shows two decimal point(as `.00`)

Here is the code.

`models.py`

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "products:product_detail",
            kwargs={
                "slug": self.slug,
            }
        )


class Variation(TimeStampedModel):
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('black', '흑백'),
        ('single', '단색'),
        ('multi', '컬러'),
    )
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0, default_currency='USD')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    color = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=COLOR_CHOICES,
        default='흑백',
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_color_display()
```

`signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Variation)
def post_save_variation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.color == 'black':
            instance.price = Money(40000, USD)
        elif instance.color == 'single':
            instance.price = Money(50000, USD)
        elif instance.color == 'multi':
            instance.price = Money(60000, USD)
        instance.save()
```

`product_detail.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load djmoney %}


{% block content %}
    <h2> Product Detail 페이지입니다!</h2>
    <p> {{ product.name }}</p>
    <p> {{ product.description }}</p>


    컬러:
    <select class="form-contorl">
        {% for variation in product.variation_set.all %}
            <option value="{{ variation.color }}"> {{ variation }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    {% money_localize product.variation_set.last.price %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

How can I deal with it? I also used `KRW`, but it also shows two deicmal points.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Since version 0.10.2 django-money has an ability to configure decimal places output.

Set `CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES` setting to `0` in your django settings module and it should work as you desired.